# Scaling multiple paths with raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, scale, raphael

I'm trying to use Raphael to create a map tool similar to this [example](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html) in the webpage.

I have an svg file of the map I want to use, and the provinces are all separate paths in the file. However, if I copy the coordinates form the svg file directly to a raphael path, the image is too large to fit the screen and therefore I need to scale it.

I know I can use the scale function to scale all province paths individually, but then they will no longer be touching each other, and I'd have to move them around to reassemble the map.

Is there a way to group the paths together and scale the whole thing, or is there some clever tool to scale the original svg file? Inkscape scaling doesn't seem to modify the coordinates in the svg file.

Thanks.

Source:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'),2000,4000);

  var province = {}
    province.a = paper.path("M 1195.23,2765.05 1176.44,2753.8 1182.93,2743.86 1198.21,2745.13 1201.92,2738.14 1239.79,2738.32 1263.62,2752.62 1284.76,2743.95 1317.8,2750.74 1367.35,2746.42 1392.66,2715.11 1400.21,2696.4 1414.4,2707.23 1451.71,2707 1456.53,2690.06 1486.98,2691.43 1517.68,2681.6 1536.64,2650.12 1560.81,2641.94 1566.44,2625.91 1655.76,2577.95 1652.86,2580.91 1640.92,2614.69 1610.92,2642.31 1590.74,2684.67 1565.32,2702.68 1559.58,2720.44 1521.84,2784.07 1477.67,2814.72 1461.87,2821.15 1442.9,2853.64 1440.5,2874.94 1420.09,2879.49 1381.85,2912.96 1374.51,2932.58 1336.52,2969.11 1318.56,2959.93 1310.72,2940.64 1294.49,2938.23 1287.2,2923.45 1265.55,2923.98 1246.43,2913.8 1239.54,2901.7 1213.98,2894.24 1206.33,2881.17 1214.32,2876.4 1199.89,2858.79 1204.99,2841.58 1220.87,2835.67 1210.72,2812.63 1232.15,2807.48 1225.15,2793.26 1231.23,2781.47 1213.41,2762.4 1195.23,2765.05 z");
    province.b = paper.path("M 1050.73,2867.78 1046.35,2845.33 1040.53,2832.74 1044.23,2819.35 1066.03,2819.42 1087.07,2805.18 1094.97,2784.45 1104.23,2779.31 1115.05,2774.95 1131.12,2800.44 1146.19,2792.66 1146.45,2777.1 1166.57,2777.52 1166.63,2804.27 1194.54,2818.11 1210.74,2812.67 1220.87,2835.67 1204.99,2841.58 1199.89,2858.79 1214.32,2876.4 1206.33,2881.17 1213.98,2894.24 1239.54,2901.7 1246.43,2913.8 1265.55,2923.98 1287.2,2923.45 1294.49,2938.23 1310.72,2940.64 1318.56,2959.93 1336.52,2969.11 1320.71,2984.32 1320.22,2994.45 1309.88,3001.29 1297.83,2993.4 1293.02,2997.09 1289.27,3013.92 1283.96,3022.6 1275.93,3022.85 1266.2,3024.26 1259.83,3020.74 1253.98,3024.67 1246.93,3031.3 1237.88,3017.88 1214.41,3015.12 1185.95,3005.82 1174.43,3017.4 1174.77,3035.97 1170.62,3043.42 1158.95,3043.06 1145.56,3029.7 1137.74,3036.82 1127.73,3037.17 1121.47,3030.56 1114.84,3035.16 1101.49,3035.03 1102.89,3011.96 1123.59,2990.26 1137.04,2989.94 1130.85,2973.55 1120.31,2972.88 1114.08,2984.93 1100.47,2983.63 1095.19,2970.61 1085.65,2970.31 1077.68,2950.18 1061.43,2942.38 1057.59,2940.54 1055.36,2924.83 1041.79,2915.84 1041.19,2898.89 1048.93,2884.2 1032.89,2877.32 1038.29,2867.02 1050.73,2867.78 z");


province.a.scale(.5, .5);  
province.b.scale(.5, .5);  }
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have some other letters in you pathString ? Does the "," stands for a "L" ?

Comment: The , only separates the x and y coordinates, but if there is no letter between coordinate pairs, the code seems to put in L as default. The effect is the same if I replace the string with:

M 1195.23,2765.05 L 1176.44,2753.8 L 1182.93,2743.86 ... ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

scale can accept four parameters:

```
scale(x, y, cx, cy);
```

where `cx` and `cy` are coordinates of the centre of scaling. By default it is in the middle of the shape. So, to scale two shapes you need to scale then relative to the same centre.

Comment: scale + translate will rescale a path, Dmitry thanks a lot for Raphael :-)

Comment: Is there an example that shows how to use the cx and cy coordinates? Thanks!

Comment: @Curious2learn: 0, 0 worked for me. For example scale(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0).

Answer (score -1):

You could join your 2 path like this :

```
province.a = paper.path("M 1195.23,2765.05 1176.44,2753.8 1182.93,2743.86 1198.21,2745.13 1201.92,2738.14 1239.79,2738.32 1263.62,2752.62 1284.76,2743.95 1317.8,2750.74 1367.35,2746.42 1392.66,2715.11 1400.21,2696.4 1414.4,2707.23 1451.71,2707 1456.53,2690.06 1486.98,2691.43 1517.68,2681.6 1536.64,2650.12 1560.81,2641.94 1566.44,2625.91 1655.76,2577.95 1652.86,2580.91 1640.92,2614.69 1610.92,2642.31 1590.74,2684.67 1565.32,2702.68 1559.58,2720.44 1521.84,2784.07 1477.67,2814.72 1461.87,2821.15 1442.9,2853.64 1440.5,2874.94 1420.09,2879.49 1381.85,2912.96 1374.51,2932.58 1336.52,2969.11 1318.56,2959.93 1310.72,2940.64 1294.49,2938.23 1287.2,2923.45 1265.55,2923.98 1246.43,2913.8 1239.54,2901.7 1213.98,2894.24 1206.33,2881.17 1214.32,2876.4 1199.89,2858.79 1204.99,2841.58 1220.87,2835.67 1210.72,2812.63 1232.15,2807.48 1225.15,2793.26 1231.23,2781.47 1213.41,2762.4 1195.23,2765.05 M 1050.73,2867.78 1046.35,2845.33 1040.53,2832.74 1044.23,2819.35 1066.03,2819.42 1087.07,2805.18 1094.97,2784.45 1104.23,2779.31 1115.05,2774.95 1131.12,2800.44 1146.19,2792.66 1146.45,2777.1 1166.57,2777.52 1166.63,2804.27 1194.54,2818.11 1210.74,2812.67 1220.87,2835.67 1204.99,2841.58 1199.89,2858.79 1214.32,2876.4 1206.33,2881.17 1213.98,2894.24 1239.54,2901.7 1246.43,2913.8 1265.55,2923.98 1287.2,2923.45 1294.49,2938.23 1310.72,2940.64 1318.56,2959.93 1336.52,2969.11 1320.71,2984.32 1320.22,2994.45 1309.88,3001.29 1297.83,2993.4 1293.02,2997.09 1289.27,3013.92 1283.96,3022.6 1275.93,3022.85 1266.2,3024.26 1259.83,3020.74 1253.98,3024.67 1246.93,3031.3 1237.88,3017.88 1214.41,3015.12 1185.95,3005.82 1174.43,3017.4 1174.77,3035.97 1170.62,3043.42 1158.95,3043.06 1145.56,3029.7 1137.74,3036.82 1127.73,3037.17 1121.47,3030.56 1114.84,3035.16 1101.49,3035.03 1102.89,3011.96 1123.59,2990.26 1137.04,2989.94 1130.85,2973.55 1120.31,2972.88 1114.08,2984.93 1100.47,2983.63 1095.19,2970.61 1085.65,2970.31 1077.68,2950.18 1061.43,2942.38 1057.59,2940.54 1055.36,2924.83 1041.79,2915.84 1041.19,2898.89 1048.93,2884.2 1032.89,2877.32 1038.29,2867.02 1050.73,2867.78 z");
```

But then you'll have only one province...

Comment: Yeah, and that's not good since I'll want to be able to select and highlight individual provinces later, like in the raphael example.