# Can't scale multiple paths in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, raphael

I've tried using the current top Question on SO : [Scaling multiple paths with raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352698/scaling-multiple-paths-with-raphael)

...without much luck. I'm building a map of the USA through Raphael and while the map is very nice, I need it to be probably 30% the size it is currently.

I was able to change the attr on the initial Raphael canvas to ".5" but that only sized each individual path instead of the whole canvas. I have also tried using javascript to scale the div containing the canvas to no avail.

Paths: Actual Page:
http://praxxgray.com/am/rafe2/mapTest.html

javascript:
http://praxxgray.com/am/rafe2/js/initMap.js

I'm new to Raphael, but I have bosses breathing down my neck to get it working. The image beneath the Raphael map shows the size that I'm aiming for. I feel like I am close, perhaps I am calling the wrong object to be resized?

Help me Obi Wan!

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, thank you folks for your answers. A solution was found using : http://www.shapevent.com/scaleraphael/

Comment: Add that as an answer yourself and mark it as correct. That way this question disappears from the Unanswered list :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter viewBox and preserveAspectRatio to the SVG element. I tried adding these parameters, just to see if I managed to change the size, and I did.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 2500 3100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

More about the viewBox attribute [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this'll help, and it's a bit off the cuff, but have you tried sticking your map in it's own raphael instance and then using Paper.setViewBox(...) to resize it?

```
 var map = Raphael(100,100,800,500);
 //
 // draw my very big map, bigger than 800x500
 //
 map.setViewBox(100,100,800,500,true); 
 // doesn't change the size of the raphael instance, but will force the graphics to fit
 // inside it.
```

[setViewBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox) lets you alter the viewport. From the link - "Sets the view box of the paper. Practically it gives you ability to zoom and pan whole paper surface by specifying new boundaries".

It might be a quick way to get what you want. It Raphael 2 only though :(

(This *should* work, but I haven't actually tested it. As I said, it's a bit off the cuff...)

Comment: This seems to be buggy for zooming in IE (6+ is deemed compatible).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this jsfiddle. I'm using this in my own map with multiple regions. Works on IE6,8 & 9

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/EUwRq/